# Change permissions for a symbolic link

Tags: symlink, chmod

I have a symlink with these permissions:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myuser myuser       38 Aug 18 00:36 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js*
```

The symlink is located in a .tar.gz archive. Now when I unpack the tar.gz archive using maven the symlink is no longer valid. I'm therefore trying to reconstruct the symlink. First I create the symlink using **ln** but how do I set the same permissions as the original symlink?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can make a new symlink and move it to the location of the old link.

```
ln -s <new_location> npm2
mv -f npm2 npm
```

That will preserve the link ownership. Alternatively, you can use `chown` to set the link's ownership manually.

```
chown -h myuser:myuser npm
```

On most systems, symlink permissions don't matter. When using the symlink, the permissions of the components of symlink's target will be checked.  However, on some systems they do matter.  MacOS requires read permission on the link for `readlink`, and NetBSD's `symperm` mount option forces link permissions checks on read and traversal.  On those systems (and their relatives, including FreeBSD and OpenBSD) there is a equivalent `-h` option to `chmod`.

```
chmod -h 777 npm
```

Comment: I just ran into a permission problem with symlinks on a CentOS 6.8 server. The symlinks had owner:group of root:root. When the owner and group were changed to the user that owned the directory they were in, as shown in this answer, the permission problem went away.

Comment: Just providing a clarification. To change ownership or rights on a symlink, the -h flag will affect the symlink file instead of the dereferenced file.

Comment: I get told that `-h` doesn't exist on `chmod` as an option!

Comment: `-h` doesnt seem to exist in debian

Comment: See also the very surprising effects of symbolic links with restrictive permissions on BSD/macOS systems described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1188707/143216) -- you may not be able to resolve the link target, but you can still read and write to it!

Answer (score 20):

When you try to use `chmod` to set the link's permissions, the actually you do is to set the permissions of the link's target.The link's permissions are meaningless.

Comment: What if someone changes the link to a malicious code? The original code can even be something that root can only access. For example in crontap scripts.

Comment: @aliqandil Generally a user can delete and recreate any file in a directory for which they have write access. In bash, for a file `test` with `-rw-rw-r-- root root`, for `rm test` I receive the prompt `rm: remove write-protected regular empty file 'test'?` The solution is to place sensitive files in directories for which users have read-only access.

Comment: this applies to Gnu `chmod` only

Answer (score 8):

When you have a link like:

```
link -> foo/bar
```

and want to change it to:

```
link -> new/target
```

There are two cases to consider:

1. `foo/bar` is not a directory or doesn't exist or you don't have search access to `foo`. Then

   ```
   ln -s new/target link
   ```

   will fail because `link` already exists, but you can overcome that by using the standard:

   ```
   ln -fs new/target link
   ```
2. `foo/bar` is a directory (and you have search permission to `foo` to be able to determine that `foo/bar` is a directory). In that case, when you do:

   ```
   ln -s new/target link
   ```

   or

   ```
   ln -fs new/target link
   ```

   That's understood as creating a new `target` symlink inside the `link` directory (`link` is a directory because it's a symlink to the `foo/bar` directory). So you'll actually create a:

   ```
   foo/bar/target -> new/target
   ```

   To overcome that, GNU `ln` has a `-T` option for the link name to always be considered as link name, and not as a directory to create the link(s) in. So, with GNU `ln`:

   ```
   ln -fsT new/target link
   ```

   will work. Like before, it will remove the original `link` symlink and create it anew with `new/target` as the target (and the process' euid and egid as the owner).

   GNU `ln` also has a `-n` option. It works like `-T` except when `link` is actually a real directory in which case it will still create the symlink inside that directory (instead of failing with an error).

   Portably, your best option is to remove the link first and then recreate it:

   ```
   rm -f link && ln -s new/target link
   ```

On most systems, permissions on symlinks are ignored and generally fixed to `rwxrwxrwx`.

On systems where symlink permissions matter (like OS/X where you need read permission to a symlink to be able to resolve its target), there's generally a way to change them (`chmod -h` on OS/X).

Ownership, while like above not relevant for access to the file pointed to by the symlink on most systems, [can have some other relevance wrt the `t` bit of the parent directory or quotas...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225620)) and there's a standard command to change it:

```
chown -h user[:group] the-link
chgrp -h group the-link
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to change symlinks permission (usually meaningless, as written in other answers), I was successful with using `-R` option of `chown`:

```
chown -R myuser:mygroup link
```

If `-R` was not used, the permissions were not changed.

Comment: That will work with GNU `chown` because `-R` implied `-P` there, however that's not guaranteed and won't work in some other chown implementations. The standard way to change the symlink ownership is with the `-h` option. I've just updated the accepted answer which was incorrect.