# How to change ownership of symbolic links?

Tags: linux, permissions, rhel, symlink, ln

I am facing some issue with creating soft links. Following is the original file.

```
$ ls -l /etc/init.d/jboss
-rwxr-xr-x 1 askar admin 4972 Mar 11  2014 /etc/init.d/jboss
```

Link creation is failing with a permission issue for the owner of the file:

```
ln -sv  jboss /etc/init.d/jboss1
ln: creating symbolic link `/etc/init.d/jboss1': Permission denied

$ id
uid=689(askar) gid=500(admin) groups=500(admin)
```

So, I created the link with sudo privileges:

```
$ sudo ln -sv  jboss /etc/init.d/jboss1
`/etc/init.d/jboss1' -> `jboss'

$ ls -l /etc/init.d/jboss1
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Jul 27 17:24 /etc/init.d/jboss1 -> jboss
```

Next I tried to change the ownership of the soft link to the original user.

```
$ sudo chown askar.admin /etc/init.d/jboss1

$ ls -l /etc/init.d/jboss1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Jul 27 17:24 /etc/init.d/jboss1 -> jboss
```

But the permission of the soft link is not getting changed.

What am I missing here to change the permission of the link?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: $ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Comment: Related: [Change permissions for a symlink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87200/313715)

Answer (score 258, accepted):

On a Linux system, when changing the ownership of a symbolic link using `chown`, by default it changes the *target* of the symbolic link (ie, **whatever the symbolic link is pointing to**).

If you'd like to change ownership of the link itself, you need to use the `-h` option to `chown`:

> **-h, --no-dereference**
>   affect  each  symbolic  link  instead of any referenced file (useful only on systems that can change the ownership of a symlink)

For example:

```
$ touch test
$ ls -l test*
-rw-r--r-- 1 mj   mj   0 Jul 27 08:47 test
$ sudo ln -s test test1
$ ls -l test*
-rw-r--r-- 1 mj   mj   0 Jul 27 08:47 test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 27 08:47 test1 -> test
$ sudo chown root:root test1
$ ls -l test*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 27 08:47 test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 27 08:47 test1 -> test
```

Note that the **target** of the link is now owned by root.

```
$ sudo chown mj:mj test1
$ ls -l test*
-rw-r--r-- 1 mj   mj   0 Jul 27 08:47 test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 27 08:47 test1 -> test
```

And again, the link `test1` is still owned by root, even though `test` has changed.

```
$ sudo chown -h mj:mj test1
$ ls -l test*
-rw-r--r-- 1 mj mj 0 Jul 27 08:47 test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mj mj 4 Jul 27 08:47 test1 -> test
```

And finally we change the ownership of the link using the `-h` option.

Comment: As a disappointing tangential: neither `cp -as` nor `install` nor `ln` can directly create symlinks with a specified user/group.

Comment: Any option to change the permission of the link and target at the same time?

Comment: THANK YOU so much for including "--no-dereference" and not just assuming everybody knows what "-h" is.  some of us are not born knowing what the cryptic switches mean!

Answer (score 32):

When acting on symlinks, you must tell most of the tools (chown, chmod, ls...) not to dereference the link: you must add the `-h` parameter, as stated in the manpage :

```
-h, --no-dereference
          affect symbolic links instead of any referenced file (useful only on systems that can change the ownership of a symlink)
```

So try : `sudo chown -h askar.admin /etc/init.d/jboss1`

Comment: The most concise answer. Most people come here because chown by its own doesn't work - the "-h" fixes this.

Answer (score 4):

Also note that the error you gave above

```
ln: creating symbolic link `/etc/init.d/jboss1': Permission denied
```

is not due to the owner of the symlink being somebody else than the owner of the original file. It is (most probably) caused by user askar not having write access to the directory `/etc/init.d`.

Comment: I figured that . Adding write permission for group was missing