# How to chown a file on a CIFS mount?

Tags: samba, chown

Here are my steps:

```
mkdir /mnt/docs
chown www-data:www-data /mnt/docs
ls -l /mnt
```

Positive results:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan  6 01:14 docs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Dec  8 21:46 cdrom
```

Now I mount the remote share successfully (I can `touch` files to it as root) like so

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.10/Public/Documents/Docs -o username=****,password="****" /mnt/docs
ls -l /mnt
```

Negative results (the owner is back to root):

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jan 12 02:51 docs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  8 21:46 cdrom
```

I then tried to `chown` the symlink like so (with -h)

```
chown -h www-data:www-data /mnt/docs
ls -l /mnt
```

But the results are still

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jan 12 02:51 docs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  8 21:46 cdrom
```

How can I mount the share to a local mount point as a non-root user? The goal is to let Apache be able to write to the remote share. Solutions for either Debian or CentOS systems are appreciated. Also, `chmod` as no effect either.

---

Related: [Symbolic link creation failing: change ownership issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218557/symbolic-link-creation-failing-change-ownership-issue)

Comment: use chown -R www-data:www-data for recursiveness

Comment: But, without -h then the target gets chown'd, not the symlink. Also, it's an empty directory. Thanks.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the way you created your samba share. If you follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way! maybe it'll help

Comment: Is your samba share created on ubuntu or debian?

Comment: I'm not sure where it resides. It's on a Linux machine that I can't SSH into.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what symlink you are referring to. What you fail to change is the owner of `/mnt/docs`, the mount-point of your CIFS share. The mount-point owner changed to the user who mounted something onto it (`root`).

Since only `root` is able to mount, how can you change the owner of the mount-point (and its underlying content)? With the `uid` and `gid` options (and also, if necessary, the `forceuid` and `forcegid` options).

See the man-page of `mount.cifs`:

> uid=arg
>
> sets the uid that will own all files or directories on the mounted filesystem 
>      when the server does not provide ownership information. It may be specified
>      as either a username or a numeric uid. When not specified, the default is uid 0.

Therefore, your `mount` command should be:

```
mount -t cifs \
      -o username=****,password="****",uid=www-data \
      //192.168.1.10/Public/Documents/Docs \
      /mnt/docs
```